# How to convert Name to Binary, JS not working when clicked, absolute beginner

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm really absolute beginner, started watching some programming videos.
I have installed VSC, but it's not showing any error when run.
Any program that is better than VSC?

I want to convert Input: Cipto to Output: 01100011 01101001 01110000 01110100 01101111

How do i do it? Please i need some easy code to understand.

```js
function convert() {
    var input = document.getElementById("name");
    var ouput = document.getElementById("number").value;
    }
output.value = "01100011 01101001 01110000 01110100 01101111";
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <body>
        <script src = "1.js"></script>
                Type in Cipto:
                <br>
                <input type = "text" id="name";
                <br>
                <button onClick="convert();">Convert!</button>
                <br>
                <br>
                Output:
                <br>
                <input type = "number" value="number";
            

        </form>
    </body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use `(input).toString(2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly you had a typo and wrote `ouput` instead of `oputput`. second, you tried to access a variable that was declared in a function from outside of his scope and it's not possible. lastly in HTML input, you should close the tag like a normal tag.

```js
function convert() {
    var input = document.getElementById("name");
    var output = document.getElementById("number");
    output.value = "01100011 01101001 01110000 01110100 01101111";
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <body>
        <script src = "1.js"></script>
                Type in Cipto:
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="name">
                <br>
                <button onClick="convert();">Convert!</button>
                <br>
                <br>
                Output:
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="number" value="number">
            

        </form>
    </body>
</head>
</html>
```

this code will work but it will always enter the same output to the input field.
if you would like to convert every input to its binary form you should write the convert function differently like so:

```js
function convert() {
  var input = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var output = document.getElementById("number");
  output.value = "";
  for (var letter of input) {
      output.value += letter.charCodeAt(0).toString(2) + " ";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <body>
        <script src = "1.js"></script>
                Type in Cipto:
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="name">
                <br>
                <button onClick="convert();">Convert!</button>
                <br>
                <br>
                Output:
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="number">
            

        </form>
    </body>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty new here so Don't be mad at me if I get the answer wrong, but you have mistakes both in the html code and the js code.
The html I've modified:

```
<head>
    <body>
        <script src = "1.js"></script>
                Type in Cipto:
                <br>
                <input type = "name" id="name">
                <br>
                <button onClick="convert();">Convert!</button>
                <br>
                <br>
                Output:
                <br>
                <input id="number">
        </form>
    </body>
</head>
</html>
```

and the JavaScript:

```
function convert() {
    var input = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var output = document.getElementById("number");
    output.value = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("number").value += input[i].charCodeAt(0).toString(2) + " ";
    }
}
```

First on html on both input forms, I've removed everything and just added an id
And in the js function I've went through every character of the input string and converted the ascii value of that character into binary. And that's it!
Hope I helped.

Comment: Also my bad in the for loop I meant to use output.value += ...

Comment: It's the same but it's shorted and you already have the output variable anyways